# How to use JPA with abstraction with WHERE clause?

Tags: jpa

So I have a GeneralDao class and classes that implement this super class.

Here is GeneralDao:

```
@Stateless
public abstract class GeneralDao<T> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Persistence")
    EntityManager em;

    public List<T> getAll(){
        TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = em.createQuery("Select t from " + getClassType().getSimpleName() + " t", getClassType());
        return typedQuery.getResultList();
    }


    public T getWithId(int id){
        TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = em.createQuery("Select t from " + getClassType().getSimpleName() + " t WHERE t." + getSimpleNameWithLowerFirstLetter() +"Id=id", getClassType());
        return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
    }

    private String getSimpleNameWithLowerFirstLetter(){
        String string = getClassType().getSimpleName();
        string = Character.toLowerCase(
                string.charAt(0)) + (string.length() > 1 ? string.substring(1) : "");
        return string;
    }

    protected abstract Class<T> getClassType();

}
```

And this is an example class that extends this class:

```
@Stateless
public class ActorDao extends GeneralDao<Actor> implements Serializable {

    @Override
    protected Class<Actor> getClassType() {
        return Actor.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Actor getWithId(int id){
        TypedQuery<Actor> typedQuery =
                em.createQuery("Select a From Actor a WHERE a.actorId =" + id,Actor.class);
        return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
    }    

}
```

Now the problem is, I can use

```
actorDao.getAll()
```

without any problems. Note that this method is not overriden.

However if I do not override

```
 actorDao.getWithId(int id)
```

I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [Select t from Actor t WHERE t.actorId=id], line 1, column 38: unknown identification variable [id]. The FROM clause of the query does not declare an identification variable [id].
```

Even the final queries are exactly the same, if it is not overriden as seen in here, it won't work.

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Hey Koray, Is this a typo ? You don't have a `getWithId()` without parameters

Comment: by the way, i'd recommed to build the queries with `String.format(formatString, parameter1, parameter2)` since that will make it a lot easier to see the final result of the concatenation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you missed a colon in your original query to mark the placeholder. Moreover, you should set that very variable for your query with the formal parameter, so what we have is:

try:

```
public T getWithId(int id){
    TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = em.createQuery("Select t from " + getClassType().getSimpleName() + " t WHERE t." + getSimpleNameWithLowerFirstLetter() +"Id= :id", getClassType());
    typedQuery.setParameter("id", id);
    return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
}
```

Also note that `getSingleResult()` throws an [exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html#getSingleResult%28%29) when there is absolutely no result, whereas `getResultList()` will just return an empty list. You can safely check it for being empty.

Comment: Again, I feel dumb. Thanks.